# MIPS: Reading a string from the command line and converting it to an itneger

Tags: assembly, command-line, mips

I am trying to write a program in MIPS assembly that reads an argument written with the `pa` ooption on the command line in order to store it in a memory register.

This is my code so far: `

```
.text
    lw $t0, 0($a1) # Stores the calue at the first index of array $a1, which is where the first command-line argument goes.
    
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1 # if my argument is, say, 5, and i try to print it out as an integer i get # 2147483643, however, if it ry to print it with 4 on $v0, nothing changes
    syscall
    j end
end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

`

I keep getting these strange numbers when I try to print the command line argument, I've already tried the `andi $t0 $t0 0x0F` with no success.

What else could I try?

I keep getting these strange numbers when I try to print the command line argument, I've already tried the `andi $t0 $t0 0x0F` and  got 11 to print out, which I guess is closer to the desired result but still far from what I want.

I've also tried to substract 48 from `$t0` to access the ascii value but so far no success.

Comment: Presumably `$t0` contains the address of the string `"5"`. You'll have to parse the contents of that string, rather than just trying to print the address.

Comment: What value is in `a0` at the start?

Comment: Are you using MARS or SPIM or something?  I assume so from the system-call numbers; Linux doesn't have a print-integer system call so I assume it's not a real-world OS like Linux.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it before but yeah I am using MARS.

Comment: AFAIK a0 has 1 at the beginning, as it is the number of arguments written